# [Protractor][Scroll] I am trying to scroll my web page using while loop. Can anyone help me understand what is wrong with code

Tags: angular, typescript, selenium, selenium-webdriver, protractor

This function is called for scrolling and then once resolves it makes browser to sleep for 2s.

```
   scrollToElement(webElement: any) {
        browser.executeScript('window.scrollTo(0,400);').then(()=>{
            console.log("sleeping"+ browser.sleep(2000));
        }).catch((err)=>{
            assert.fail("failed to scroll");
        }); 
    }
```

Calling function snippet:

```
while(!(arr[0]===arr[2])){
            console.log('scroll');
            utils.scrollToElement(this.scrollUpLink);
            countTop = utils.getTextfrom(this.getTotalcountOnTop);
             let arrIn=countTop.split(" ");
             arr[0]=arrIn[0];
             arr[2]=arrIn[2];
             console.log(" Indisde :"+arr[0]+ " "+ arr[2]);
        }
```

Here,I am checking equality of two string and scrolling till both are not same.

```
The output that I get is:
scroll
 Indisde :24 434
scroll
 Indisde :24 434
scroll
 Indisde :24 434
scroll
 Indisde :24 434
```

Comment: Hi @Sachin Joshi, What is your question here? I mean what is not working and what is the expected behavior?

Comment: Hi, I am actually trying to scroll the page till condition is true. But it's not happening.

Comment: Ok, what is `getTotalcountOnTop`? where are you getting it from? Is it getting incremented each time when you do the scrolling? Try to provide more info...

Comment: Yes, Ideally when scroll is successful, it recounts the value and assign new value using arr[0]=arrIn[0] likewise and then again check for equality. but since scroll is not working, products are not loaded and count remains unchanged and hence, while goes on executing.

Comment: `window.scrollTo()` may be not working in your case or it is a wrong call... Try to use `document.scrollTo()` instead of window and as you are passing some argument to `scrollToElement` method, you can use `driver.executeScript("arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true)", element)` to perform it effectively... Let me know the status after trying this and post if you are getting any exceptions...

Comment: No..it is not working with above solution.I am getting same result. Interestingly, If I use "if" condition instead of "while" it works fine with my code. But that would scroll only once which means scrollTo() is fine. I think it has issue with promise call which remains pending.

Comment: Ok, I think the problem is you are not incrementing 400 value in this `window.scrollTo(0,400);`  may be because of that it is not performing the scrolling

Comment: check out my answer, modify your code accordingly. I hope it works...

Answer (score 0):

Your code has some implementation problems, I mean you are not handling `Promise`s properly and you are not increasing `400` value in `window.scrollTo(0,400);`.

And you are using `sleep()` in then() so, below is the code I have tried based on your code and which is completely working fine, so change your code accordingly and try to run :

```
// Declaring driver
var driver = null;

// Funtion to perform scroll
async function scrollToElement(xValue, yValue) {
    await driver.executeScript('window.scrollTo('+xValue+', '+yValue+');')
}

// Function which passes counter to a scrolling function and waits 2 seconds before doing the scroll 
async function doScroll() {
    // Initializing the driver
    driver = await browser.setup('chrome');
    // Launching the chrome and navigating to google.com
    await driver.get('http://www.google.com');
    // Searching something in the google
    await driver.findElement(By.name('q')).sendKeys('alicse3'+Key.ENTER);
    // Calling the scrolling funciton
    let i = 0, xValue = 0, yValue = 100;
    while(i++ <= 5) {
        await scrollToElement(xValue, yValue+=100);
        await console.log("=> The 'i' value is " + i);
        await driver.sleep(2000);
    }
}

// Executor function
doScroll();
```

I hope it helps...